# How do I generate a new App Secret for LinkedIn Application?

Tags: linkedin-api

We wanted to refresh our app secret key. How can this be done without having to create a whole new application as we have 1000's of people already connected to the application and creating a new app would cause a disturbance.

We can't find any documentation on how this can be done currently without having to create a whole new app.